# ASP.NET Core MVC : custom HtmlHelper adding sections

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm attempting to create a custom dropdown as an `HtmlHelper` to be used like `Html.MyDropdown(x => x.MyList)`. I would like to add a css file to it like this:

```
public static class HtmlHelpers
{
   public static IHtmlContent MyDropdown<TModel>(this IHtmlHelper<TModel> model, Expressoion<Func<TModel,DropdownViewModle>> expression)
   {
       var builder = new StringBuilder(@"<div class=""dropdown""/>");

       // some other content here

       builder.AppendLine("</div>")

       // this is my question
       builder.AppendLine("@section Styles{~/css/dropdown.css}");
       builder.AppendLine("@section Scripts{~/js/dropdown.js}");

       return new HtmlString(builder.ToString());
    }
}
```

How can I make the helper add the css and js file so the implementor doesn't have to?

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier if you just add in the CSS and Javascript like this:

```
var builder = new StringBuilder(@"<div class=""dropdown""/>");

// some other content here

builder.AppendLine("</div>");

var css = @"
<style>
.style{
display: block;
}
</style>

";
            
var js = @"
<script>
doStuff(){
    console.log('Hello World');
}
</script>

";
            
builder.Append(css);
builder.Append(js);

return new HtmlString(builder.ToString());
```